# python3 implementing a data descriptor in metaclass

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass, python-descriptors

What is the correct way to implement a data descriptor inside a metaclass? In the following (trivial) example, I wish to always append a question mark to the desired value before setting it:

```
class AddQDesc:

  def __init__ (self, name):
    self.name = name
  
  def __get__ (self, instance, owner=None):
    obj = instance if instance != None else owner
    return obj.__dict__[self.name]
  
  def __set__ (self, instance, value):
    # What should go here ?
    #setattr(instance, self.name, "{}?".format(value))  <- This gives me recursion error
    #instance.__dict__[self.name] = "{}?".format(value) <- This gives me proxymapping error
    pass

class Meta (type):
  var = AddQDesc("var")

class C (metaclass=Meta):
  var = 5

print(C.var)
C.var = 1
print(C.var)
```

First, it looks like the descriptor was not used when I initialized var to 5. Can I somehow apply descriptor protocol here as well? (Make it "5?")
Second, how should the value be updated in the __set__ method? Updating the __dict__ gives me ***"TypeError: 'mappingproxy' object does not support item assignment"*** and using setattr gives me ***"RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"***.

Comment: I cannot answer properly to your question, but you can probably take a look at the [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) class or at this [Descriptor howto guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) from the python documentation.

What i can say though is that in

```python
class C (metaclass=Meta):
  var = 5
```

You replaced  the attribute "var" from the metaclass by an entirely different attribute, which is normal: inheritance is about overriding the parent class' behavior.

Comment: yes - it is tricky -  I am on track, but no time right now. It will be a _lot_ easier if you don't need to actually store the attribute in the class.__dict__ with the same name - that is easy for ordinary objects. But if the name can be a mangled name (like "_var"), or if the data storage can be in the descriptor instance, instead of the class, it would be straightforward.

Comment: Howver, being able to specify an initial value in the class body may be an interesting side-problem. I don't know itf type.__new__, which will set these initial attributes, will make use of the descriptor protocol at all - will check later.

Comment: (as it turns out,  `type.__new__` ignores  descriptors in the metaclass to assign initial class attributes - my answer includes a workaround for that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented in the question, this is tricky - because there is no way from Python code to change a class' `__dict__` attribute directly - one have to call `setattr` and let Python set a class attribute - and, `setattr` will "see" the descriptor in the metaclass, and call its `__set__` instead of modifying the value in the class `__dict__` itself. So, you get an infinite recursion loop.

Therefore, if you *really* require that the attribute proxied by the descriptor will "live" with the same name in the class'dict, you have to resort to: when setting the value, temporarily remove the descriptor from the metaclass, call `setattr` to set the value, and then restoring it back.

Also, if you want the values set in the class body to be handled
through the descriptor, they have to be set with `setattr` after the
class is created - `type.__new__` won't check for the descriptor
as it builds the initial class `__dict__`.

```py
from threading import Lock

class AddQDesc:

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.lock = Lock()
    
    def __get__ (self, instance, owner=None):
        obj = instance if instance != None else owner
        return obj.__dict__[self.name]
    
    def __set__ (self, instance, value):
        owner_metaclass = type(instance)
        
        with self.lock:
            # Temporarily remove the descriptor to avoid recursion problems
            try:
                # Note that a metaclass-inheritance hierarchy, where
                # the descriptor might be placed in a superclass
                # of the instance's metaclass, is not handled here.
                delattr(owner_metaclass, self.name)
                setattr(instance, self.name, value + 1)
            finally:
                setattr(owner_metaclass, self.name, self)
      

class Meta (type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
        post_init = {}
        for key, value in list(namespace.items()):
            if isinstance(getattr(mcls, key, None), AddQDesc):
                post_init[key] = value
                del namespace[key]
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
        for key, value in post_init.items():
            setattr(cls, key, value)
        return cls
    
                
    var = AddQDesc("var")

class C (metaclass=Meta):
    var = 5

print(C.var)
C.var = 1
print(C.var)
```

If you don't need the value to live in the class' `__dict__`, I'd suggest just storing it elsewhere - a dictionary in the descriptor instance for example, having the classes as keys, will suffice - and will be far less weird.

```py
class AddQDesc:

    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.storage = {}
        
    def __get__ (self, instance, owner):
        if not instance: return self
        return self.storage[instance]
            
    
    def __set__ (self, instance, value):
        self.storage[instance] = value + 1
```